# how to specify the week, month, and year

Tags: dates

How do you specify the week, month, and year? If I were to compose a cover for a newsletter, would the following be okay?

> Week 3, March 2022

Comment: Do you mean that this is the third issue of a weekly newsletter, or that it is the issue for the third week in March? If the latter, I think most periodicals would simply give the date, either of the day of issue or the 'week ending' date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most periodicals do not specify a numbered week. They give either the starting date of the week, (as in "week of March 6, 2022) or they give the range of dates, (as in "week of March 6-12, 2022") or most often simply given the publication date (as "March 7, 2022)" and depend on a separate,statement that the publication is weekly. (Of course any of the standard date forms may be used, whichever would normally be used for a date in the same publication, such as "6 March 2022" or "03/06/2022".)

However, in some business contexts, the cumulative week of the calendar year or a fiscal year is significant.  In such a case one might use "Week 10; March 6, 2022"

In some church related publications one might see something like "5th Sunday in Ordinary time"